# MVC app not redirecting to original Action but redirect to Home controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using bootstrap in My ASP.net MVC application. When I redirect it to any action in Admin controller, it redirects it to the home controller, only index of Admin controller is working correctly.
Basically the app logins from Home controller and redirect it to Admin controller and this problem occurs in Admin controller.

I tried many things like

```
return RedirectToAction("Student","Admin"),
return View();
return View("Student"); 
<a href="@Url.Action("Student")">Students</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("Student","Admin")">Students</a>
<a href="~/Admin/Student">Students</a>
<a href="Admin/Student">Students</a>
@Html.ActionLink("Students","Student","Admin")
```

but not even a single thing worked.

Layout Page:

```
    <div class="left-side-inner">
         <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked custom-nav">
                <li><a href="~/Admin/Index" ><i class="lnr lnr-power-switch"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="~/Admin/Student"> <i class="lnr lnr-cog"></i><span>Students</span> </a> </li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Teacher","Admin")"> <i class="lnr lnr-cog"></i> <span>Teachers</span></a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

Admin Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  if (Session["USERNAME"] == null)
    return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index","Home");

  return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Student()
{
  if (Session["USERNAME"] == null)
    return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "Home");

  return View();
}
```

LogIn :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(LogIn logIn)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            { 
                string q = "select ROLE,NAME from login where USERNAME = '" + logIn.USERNAME + "' and Password = '" + logIn.PASSWORD + "'";
                SqlDataReader sdr = db.Select(q);
                if (sdr.Read())
                {
                    string Role = sdr[0].ToString();
                    string NAME = sdr[1].ToString();
                    sdr.Close();
                    if (Role.ToLower().Equals("admin"))
                    {
                        Session["USERNAME"] = logIn.USERNAME;
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                    }
                    else if (Role.ToLower().Equals("teacher"))
                    {
                        Session["USERNAME"] = logIn.USERNAME;
                        Session["NAME"] = NAME;
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Teacher");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Oops! Some Error Occured. Kindly Inform Admin.');</script>");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Invalid Username or Password');</script>");
                }
                sdr.Close();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Nothing is working and every time it redirects me back to Home controller, Index Action.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code of `public ActionResult Index(LogIn logIn)` while debugging to see why it isn't setting `Session["USERNAME"]`?

Comment: you might want to specify area explicitly in the code, MVC is contextual and might cause issue with redirect

Comment: Don't roll your own authentication system. You now have an SQL injection vulnerability. Just use ASP.NET Identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change this line in your Admin controller from:

```
return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "Home");
```

to:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

RedirectToActionPermanent tells the browser that the original resource has permanently moved to a new location; therefore it must cache this location.

Once done, you should clear the browser cache and try again.

Comment: Thanks alot for the solution.